# SQL query into a Google Apps Script (*.gs)

Tags: javascript, sql, google-sheets

I am beginner in *.gs and javascript (*.js) code and I want to write a Google Apps script including an SQL query to apply it to one or more Google Sheets tabs :

- tab where I write my *.gs code : CRA_COMPILE
- tab on which the code applies : CRA_MAI_Philippe
- my current code to correct and complete :

```
// Add data source with query parameter.
function addDataSource() {
  SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Add a new sheet and use A1 cell as the parameter cell.
  //var parameterCell = spreadsheet.insertSheet('Détail').getRange('A4:CV19');
//parameterCell.setValue('Duke');

// Add data source with query parameter.
  var dataSourceSpec = SpreadsheetApp.newDataSourceSpec()
      .asBigQuery()
      .setProjectId('SQL')
      .setRawQuery('select * from `bigquery-public-data`')
      .setParameterFromCell('CRA_MAI_Philippe', 'Détail!A4:CV19')
      .build();
  //var dataSourceSheet = spreadsheet.insertDataSourceSheet(dataSourceSpec);
  //dataSourceSheet.asSheet().setName('Détail');
}
```